# Can not remove ERR_NGROK_6024 when using Shopify App Proxy get call

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, ngrok

I am trying to send data using app proxy, from the localhost, I am using ngrok but not able to visit the page.

Also not able ( Or probably not knowing how to ), pass request hedges "ngrok-skip-browser-warning"

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I was facing same issue today. It worked by adding this header "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "69420".

[solution source](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/ACEJS/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Add the header "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "69420" with a browser extension like ModHeader.
https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/modheader-modify-http-h/opgbiafapkbbnbnjcdomjaghbckfkglc?refid=bingshortanswersdownload