# Axios don't set up default headers

Tags: axios, header, react-query, request-headers

#### Hello everyone!

**Yesterday I faced with issue, in order to omit some warning from ngrok, I have to add additional header to get my data from db.**
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlUUh.png)
I use axios to make a request to api and I also use ngrok as free host, to up my frontend and fake-api (json-server). I found a solution here: [Can not remove ERR_NGROK_6024 when using Shopify App Proxy get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518334/can-not-remove-err-ngrok-6024-when-using-shopify-app-proxy-get-call)
But now when I add this header to my request next way:

```js
const result = await axios.get(
   `${BASE_API_URL}/db`,
    {
        headers: {
            "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": 69420
        }
}
                
     );
```

All default headers are deleting:
[Headers with additional header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrKPJ.png)

And as you can see all my default headers disappeared

If I make normal request without additional header:

```js
const result = await axios.get(`${BASE_API_URL}/db`);
```

All default headers appear there next way:
[Headers without additional header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlr0w.png)
**But in order to fix my issue I have to add this header, I can't get why when I add additional header axios delete all other default headers at all?**

I tried to set up default headers next way:

```
queryFn: async () => {
            axios.defaults.headers["ngrok-skip-browser-warning"] = 69420;
            const result = await axios.get(`${BASE_API_URL}/db`);
            return result.data as DashBoard;
        },
```

I still get the same problem, that axios don't set up default headers
I followed by this guide from original axios documentation:
https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.